# Force DataGrid update when ItemsSource has converter applied

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid, converters, itemssource

ItemsSource: an ObservableCollection of raw data.
Converter: generating a view model by applying a complex non-linear transform on ItemsSource. Converter output is a plain list.

I know the design is wrong, I should create view model layer with NotifyPropertyChanged events, but this is a quick prototype for something, I'm just hoping there is an easy trick to force the DataGrid rerun converter whenever ItemsSource updates.

Comment: What is so hard about adding a string property and moving what you have in the converter?

Comment: @BalamBalam, the converter is not converting at item level but list level and the transform is not a simple mapping. A similar example is to convert a list of calendar events, each has a start time and a duration, to a list of datetime, each has bool properties "something starts here" and "something ends here".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fire property-level change notifications when the collection changes, this forces a reevaluation of the `ItemsSource` binding.

i.e.

```
//Data being the ObservableCollection
Data.CollectionChanged += (s,e) => OnPropertyChanged("Data");
```

Comment: Is "Data" the ObservableCollection assigned to ItemsSource? Where should I put this snippet to?

Comment: @user986080: If you allow the property to change you should attach the handler in the setter of the property (you also should then use a named method and detach the handler from the previous instance assigned to the property). If the backing field of the property is readonly (which i would strongly recommend) you can put this in the constructor of the owning class as the instance will never change anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Where does the change to your collection come from - a button? If it is just a prototype then I would use a List, put a CollectionView in between and call CollectionView.Refresh() to refresh explicit.

The solution with OnPropertyChanged("Data"); looks like it could loop.